# Postgresql Cursor in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How do I view the contents of a returns Postgresql cursor?

I have a custom function in Postgresql that returns a cursor. In Rails the returned values looks like an array that contains:

```
#<Order:0x007f6b63a49220> and #<Order:0x007f6b63a49040>
```

when I try to view the contents of these using .first or [0] I get an error

edit:

**index.html.erb**

```
<p><% @results %>
<p><% @results.each do |k,v| %>
        <p><%= "key: #{k}" %></p>
        <p><%= "value: #{v}" %></p>
<% end %></p>
```

**test_controller.erb**

```
@results = Order.retention_data(shop_id)
```

**YYYYMMDD__add_process_functionstToDb.rb**

```
class AddProcessFunctionstToDb < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    funcs = File.read(Rails.root.join('db', 'migrate', 'processfunctions.sql').to_s)
    execute funcs
  end
  def down
  end
end
```

**processfunctions.sql**

```
drop function if exists retention_data(ref refcursor, shopId integer);
create or replace function retention_data(ref refcursor, shopId integer) returns refcursor as $$
    begin
    open ref for
...
    close ref;
    return ref;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

edit2:

I tried

```
k.attribute_names
```

and it returned

```
"retention_data", "id"
```

they returned:

```
k.retention_data #> x (the name of the cursor)
k.id #> (nothing)
```

others:

```
@results.responds_to? #>undefined method `responds_to?' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Order id: nil>, #<Order id: nil>]>
```

Comment: how you get this Order?? (query)

Comment: added in the code

Comment: sorry, never use rails with sql functions. What get with `puts k.inspect` and `puts k.class`